# What "Wrong path" is Colin referring to?

Tags: black-mirror, bandersnatch

In *Black Mirror: Bandersnatch* (2018), Stefan shows his 3D Maze game to Mohan's team. Meanwhile
Satpal brought chocolates to Mohan:

> Satpal: Here you go.
>
> Mohan: Happy Birthday to me.
>
> (*Colin says to Stefan*)
>
> Colin: Sorry, mate. **Wrong path**

What "Wrong path" is Colin referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The central conceit of *[Black Mirror: Bandersnatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Mirror:_Bandersnatch)* is that it is a branching story. This line is a Meta acknowledgement of that structure with the character stating that line pointed toward the camera (albeit not directly looking into it) as he says it.

**TL;DR It's a wrong story path**

[image: Image of Colin saying "Sorry, mate. Wrong Path"]